# how to use digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt-runtime:compass-support in wercker?

Tags: node.js, docker, compass, wercker

I m using [wercker](http://wercker.com/) to automate deployment of nodejs application.

I thought [`digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt-runtime` box](https://hub.docker.com/r/digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt-runtime/) with compass support will make the job.

But when [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) attempts to use [compass](http://compass-style.org/) it is going to error.

extract of my `werker.yml`

```
box: digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt-runtime:compass-support
build:
  steps:
    - wercker/npm-install
    - greatbeyond/bower-install@0.5.8
    - wercker/grunt:
      stack: true
      fail-on-warnings: true
      tasks: clean ngconstant:production build
```

extract of the `grunt` log concerning `compass`

```
 Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
   Warning: Command failed: /bin/sh -c compass --version
   /bin/sh: 1: compass: not found
   Use --force to continue.
   Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c compass --version
   /bin/sh: 1: compass: not found
```

Seems I m missing a step.

How to make `compass` work in the box?

Answer (score 1):

I tried downloading the docker container (`digitallyseamless/nodejs-bower-grunt-runtime:compass-support`), when inspecting the content of the container I was not able to find `compass` on that container.

It turns out the `Dockerfile` for that container uses the `ONBUILD` directive when installing compass: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#onbuild

So it will only install `compass` when creating a new Docker container from this base image (though it also expects the entire application to be present already).

You could create a PR to remove the `ONBUILD` directive from the `apt-get ...` commands, thus making `compass` part of this container.